# Need more than two external interrupts in 8051

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, interrupts, 8051

I am working with 8 YS-17 flame sensors and may need more in the future. There are only two INT0 and INT1 in port 3.  Is there any way to get the other interrupts or I/Os to work as external interrupts?

The microcontroller is an [AT89S52](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc1919.pdf) and the oscillator is running at 16MHz.

Comment: It was common practice to use a single interrupt pin for multiple interrupts in small microprocessors and microcontrollers and let the interrupt handler work out which device caused the interrupt.

Comment: but how to use a single interrupt pin for multiple interrupts ? @PeterSmith

Comment: Why on earth you even need an interrupt at all? Does it matter if you detect flames with 1 microsecond or 1 second accuracy?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use an I/O expander such as the [MCP23017 or MCP23S17](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/20001952C-1129816.pdf) (I²C or SPI).  These chips can record an interrupt on any of 16 pins and report it over a single (additional) pin.  Reading two 8-bit registers will tell you which of the 16 pins sent the interrupt.  This chip is also available in an 8-port version ([MCP23008 or MCP23S08](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/21919b-65915.pdf)).

Comment: MCP23017 or MCP23S17 don't exist in the ICs markets

Comment: @KiroloesAmir [Check here](https://www.mouser.com/Microchip/Semiconductors/Interface-ICs/Interface-I-O-Expanders/_/N-aq4ecZ1yzvvqxZscv7Zgjdhub?P=1yvm6qfZ1yvm6pxZ1yt3p67Z1z0zl2wZ1yzudtpZ1yzunb9&Ns=Pricing%7c0&FS=True), for example.

Comment: @AlexHajnal the link you suggest gives "0 results". Perhaps the parts are available in some countries, not in others?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Perhaps.  Normally their site will optionally redirect to a local branch if you're not in the US.  Given that Mouser is a US company it's prohibited from doing business with some countries (Iran, North Korea, etc.) by [ITAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Traffic_in_Arms_Regulations) so might return no results for that country.  Just conjecture on my part; the search gives the same results on a number of their sites (USA, France, Thailand, India, Estonia, Turkey, China).